# PostgreSql - Queries not executed correctly within PgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have installed PostgreSql 9.6 for Windows. And a problem arised with PgAdmin 4. First of all the UI looks corrupted: some lines between the components of a tree on the left side are missing. 
Also queries are not executed correctly.

For example, when creating a table, the query returns successfully. However the table is not actually displayed after refreshing the Tables or Schemas component on the left. As well as the `SELECT * FROM emp;` query returns successfully but doesnt show any data.

This is the first time I'm facing such a problem with PostgreSql for two years working with it. And I haven't fount any relevant information after researching the issue. Will be grateful for any hints about the possible cause of such beahavoiur. Especially confusing is the currupted UI. Could it be that I need to install additional libraries?

Installation of PostgreSql 10.2 instead of 9.6 did not solve the problem.

I've also noticed that when clicking a `+` to expand the components on the left, they are all empty and don't look as usual in PgAdmin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows a `CREATE TABLE` statement. That does not return any rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The problem is that the table is not created at all. No data was returned after I've tried to insert data as well.

Comment: And what does the commandline client psql say? Or:pgadmin3 ?

Answer (score 0):

There were many issues in pgAdmin4 runtime(aka Desktop application) which was built on top of Qt5.

Could you try again with latest development version, Download: https://developer.pgadmin.org/~dpage/runtime-revamp/

Let us know if that solves your problem.

Comment: This is very strange but the version of pgAdmin that you suggested gets opened as a browser version. And I don't see the way to open it as a desktop application. Also I tried to create tables and perform selects from command line and everything woks perfect. The pgAdmin version from your link has a correct graphics but still not possible to create tables in it. I would like to figure out how to get pgAdmin working as well.